# Does the Android Management API give a way to grant the "Media Projection" setting for a specific app?

Tags: android, android-management-api

Is it possible using the Android Management API to allow "Media Projection" to be configured for a specific application within a policy?

This is the setting I am referring to:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/media-projection

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Android Management API does not allow granting [Media Projection](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/media-projection) settings for specific apps, since it is not an app-specific settings [Resource policy](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#resource:-policy).

If you want to stay up to date with the latest updates for Android enterprise, we suggest that you [join the Android Management API mailing list](https://developers.google.com/android/management/release-notes) to receive monthly updates and service advisories directly to your inbox.